# Cron не выполняет кусок кода

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Файл с кодом парсера Excel файла

```
    $tmpfname = "sale/Internet.xls";
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
```

После второй строчки код не выполняется дальше, хотя если открыть в браузере то успешно код выполняется. Подскажите что может быть ?

Comment: Стандартный вопрос: что в логах? :) Попробуйте добавить в хвост к команде `> /tmp/file.log 2>&1` и потом почитать что там появится

Comment: У меня это php файл.. как данную команду можно дописать ?

Comment: Как вы добавляете задачу в крон?

Comment: 45 8 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sale.php

Comment: Проблемма решена, в скрипте был относительный путь к файлу